# After upgrading to 20.04 my Gnome Software Centre has problems displaying a list of installed applications

Tags: software-center

Immediately after the upgrade, the INSTALLED tab in the Gnome Software Centre was completely empty.
I reinstalled Software Centre

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

All my applications were back. However, when I launched the Centre the other day, the INSTALLED tab was again empty. I do not know
when the Installed List disappeared again.
I believe that if I reinstall again, this may help. I have not tried it yet. But, reinstalling the Centre every time
before using it is not an option.
Can someone help to understand what is happening?.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you definitely running the same application each time? The pre-installed store application on 20.04 is a snap application (can be launched by `snap-store`). You also installed GNOME Software (can be launched by `gnome-software`). Run the two separately, check the differences and report back.

Comment: snap-store means Ubuntu Software Centre. Good. When I wrote my question, I simplified my case. In fact the case was as follows.
After 20.04 upgrade I opened Ubuntu Software Centre. I found the “Installed” tab is empty. I opened Gnome Software Centre. "Installed" tab was  empty, too, Next, I re-installed both Centres.
Gnome Centre began to display "Installed", but, in Ubuntu Centre the list was empty. However, later, the Installed tab has disappeared in Gnome Centre again.

Comment: I will add more information.  Typically, the "Installed" list is empty in both Centers, Ubuntu and Gnome. I am able to install software using one of the Centers. Then I see on the “Installed” tab only this last installed program, but later, most likely, after rebooting, the “Installed” list again becomes completely empty.

Comment: I confirmed that the Installed list becomes empty after rebooting..

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. I noticed that the list of installed applications is randomly either empty or full in both Ubuntu Center and Gnome Center. The presence of two centers confuses me very much. I am a typical Ubuntu desktop user, and cannot understand why there are two functionally identical Centers, and when I received two Centers instead of one. Both, look the same. Even when I install the update in any center, I see a progress bar in both centers at the same time. Anyway, I returned to the empty list problem. I don’t know why, but both gnome-software and the snap-store are active in the background after exiting the GUI. The last time my Installed list was empty, I detected and killed a running snap-store in the background. Then I ran the GUI again, and after a while, my list returned to Ubuntu and Gnome Centers.
I will report this error for both gnome-software and snap-store.